# sort data in file with bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I have following file:

```
# cat /var/data/wlan_cells.log
"Tech 1" "57" "-67" "0"
"GUEST01" "52" "-69" "0"
"SWSGP01" "52" "-69" "0"
"GateAP" "100" "-39" "0"
"AP_9 test" "78" "-59" "0"
"surf" "13" "-85" "0"
"Tech 2" "18" "-83" "0"
```

How can I sort the lines by signal quality (second value)?
Expected result:

```
# cat /var/data/wlan_cells.log
"GateAP" "100" "-39" "0"
"AP_9 test" "78" "-59" "0"
"Tech 1" "57" "-67" "0"
"GUEST01" "52" "-69" "0"
"SWSGP01" "52" "-69" "0"
"Tech 2" "18" "-83" "0"
"surf" "13" "-85" "0"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use

```
sort -t\" -k4nr
```

i.e. split to columns by `"`, use the fourth column, sort numerically in reversed order.

Comment: Was expecting elegant solutions using AWK (which lends itself to these sort of things). But this is even better.

Comment: I love it, even if I don't understand it :)

Comment: That command splits every line of your log in columns. A new column is created everytime a **"** symbol is seen. So for example, in the first line the columns will be: a void column (because the first symbol met is a **"** The second column will be Tech 1. The third column will be a space. The fourth column will be 57. The sort command then sorts the fourth columns (the signal quality) of the log lines.